# Convert string to decimal with space as thousands sepreator

Tags: c#, string, parsing, decimalformat

i am trying to convert a string "1 180,5" to a decimal value
but its not working

```
string a ="1 180,5"
var value = Decimal.Parse(a)
```

even trying with this method

```
string a ="1 180,5"
var value = Decimal.Parse(a,NumberStyles.AllowThousands)
```

didnt work still throwing format exception

Comment: First, always is a better idea to use x.TryParse instead x.Parse. Second use the swedish culture (they uses space as thousands separator) or replace space for dot and use a standard culture for the TryParse

Answer (score 0):

Space character (' ') is thousands separator only in some cultures. Use `Decimal.Parse` method variant that accepts a culture, and provide a proper culture to it.

Comment: To provide a working example, Decimal.Parse(a, new CultureInfo("fr-FR")); would parse the string properly. "fr-FR" is one example, but you should choose the culture string that makes sense in the context of this app.